# Softlayer api: How to identify two vlans are matching VLAN router pair?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

## background

I get a exception when I order a VSI with specified the fronted and backend vlans.

The place order para of vlans are marked as

```
order_template = {...
'virtualGuests': [{'primaryBackendNetworkComponent': {'networkVlan': {'id': 2058375}}, 'domain': 'xxx', 'hostname': 'xxx', 'primaryNetworkComponent': {'networkVlan': {'id': 1698647}}
...}
```

The Exception as flow:

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): When specifying frontend and backend VLANs, they must be on the appropriate router pair. The specified backend VLAN is on router `bcr02a.hkg02`, so the specified frontend VLAN should be on router `fcr02a.hkg02`. However, the specified frontend VLAN is on router `fcr01a.hkg02`. Please specify a matching VLAN router pair.
```

I known that `fcr01a` must match to `bcr01a`.

```
#get vlan info
object_mask = 'mask[id,name,primarySubnetId,vlanNumber,networkSpace,primaryRouter[id,datacenter[id,name]]]'
account.getNetworkVlans(mask=object_mask)
```

result:

```
vlans = [
                {'primaryRouter': {'datacenter': {'id': 352494, 'name': 'hkg02'}, 'id': 212460}, 'primarySubnetId': 987829, 'vlanNumber': 1461, 'id': 1698651},...]
```

## question

How can I get the more information to check the frontend and bakcend are are matching VLAN router pair or not ?

Or, How can I set the mask to get fcr01a.hkg02 when I call account.getNetworkVlans?

Or, Is there any other item of vlan info to identity the pair relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order To obtain more information about the vlan pair routing the Product_Order::getVlans will help you as it retrieves the available private and public vlans during ordering, you may use the locationId you provided as value (352494) to narrow the result, don´t forget that this value should match the datacenter you are using along the placeOrder method. For example use this on your python script:

```
locationId = 352494 #location id for Hong Kong 02 datacenter 
packageId = 46 #package for VSI.

result = client['Product_Order'].getVlans(locationId, packageId)
```

Or you may review the following url for a better script using Account::getNetworkVlans
[Ordering Softlayer Vlan pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511624/ordering-softlayer-vlan-pairs)

You may improve your code by adding the property “hostname” to your mask and using Object Filters to search for required value, you may try the following improvement of your code:

```
objectMask=mask[id,name,primarySubnetId,vlanNumber,networkSpace,primaryRouter[id,hostname, datacenter[id,name]]]
objectFilter={"networkVlans":{"primaryRouter":{"hostname":{"operation":"fcr01a.hkg02"}}}}

account.getNetworkVlans(mask=object_mask, filter=objectFilter)
```

For more information please see below:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/getVlans

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. The object mask you offered helps me to get the host name of a vlan. Then I can check the pair relationship according the host name like bcr02a.hkg02 and fcr02a.hkg02.  While, could you tell me how can I get more object mask when I set the mask to a softlayer api?  Usually, I know which api to use according sldn, but am confused which mask item can be used to get more information ...

Comment: I recomend you to read this https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks, in order to know what items can be used in the object mask you need to see documentation for example the method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans is returning a data of type http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan so you can see all their items there and you can use them in your object mask. As you can see you only need to know what data type your request is returning and you can see in documentation all the valid items for the mask of it